# Horizontal scroll bar problem in IE7 + IE8

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 + IE8 there is a problem with the background when the browser is set at a small size (1024 x 768 for example).  The background extends out very far to the right, causing a horizontal scroll bar.

Here is a screenshot of the bug.

[image]

When viewing the site at 1024x768, the layout should be centered on the content area with no horizontal scroll.

Help!

Comment: the `doctype` is set to html4 strict, maybe try html4 transitional instead.  http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used relative positioning in situations where it was really not necessary or appropriate. In the process you set some very odd measurements to get the layout you wanted. The fix mainly involves removing a lot of your relative positioning styling.

If you replace the three rules I have given you below it should fix your problem.

```
.rightmenu .leftCol {
    margin-top: -61px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.rightmenu .col1wrap {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    width: 50%;
}
.rightmenu .col2 {
    border-left: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
    min-height: 1000px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    width: 212px;
    float: right;
}
```

I noticed you had duplicated a few of the rules above in another style sheet. You should completely remove those duplicate rules and only use the three above to ensure there are no conflicts.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That worked perfectly.  You saved me quite a bit of time.  The CSS is a bit of a mess due to all the overrides, so I've been having a hard time.  I have another question open about a couple other problems in IE7 if you've got some time to take a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700025/css-problem-with-navigation-and-search-filters-in-ie7