# CSS problem with navigation and search filters in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

These are **IE7 Only** problems:

**Navigation Problem**

The active tab "jumps" whenever a user hovers on an inactive tab.

Screenshot:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6688069/navi.jpg

**Search Filter Problem**

I can't seem to get the height correct in IE7 without breaking the functionality.

Screenshot of what is should look like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6688069/filter.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm seeing is that in IE7 this element:

```
<ul class="multiselect" id="multi-filtercountry"/>
```

is causing it those list items to expand... I also noticed that in Chrome, a real browser, none of those sidebar elements are expanding their parent. That means to me that you have one floating element in there somewhere, and the others aren't.

If you use Chrome's developer tools and mouse over the elements inside `<span class="expanded">` you'll see that their position is determined to be up top, meaning they aren't flowing properly.

My best advice is to try to look at this not as an IE7 problem but a markup problem in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I set ul.multiselect to "display:none;" in IE7, and that did the trick without breaking the functionality.  Any idea about the active tab "jumping"???